# How to access a WPF control inside System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel-loop

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

First i have to guess that i got not much experience with async.

I'm working with VS2015 on a WPF application, in which i have a mask designer.
There i can add controls to a canvas by drag-and-drop, move and resize them.
The changes in size and position are temporarely stored in a dictionary and saved later to the database by clicking a Save-button.

For optimizing the speed of the updates, i thought it would be good to replace the synchronous foreach by an asynchronous System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach.
But now i have the problem, that i cannot use some WPF controls - like the canvas on which the controls are lying - inside that loop, because they belong to the main thread.

How can i access these controls inside the loop?

Here is an experpt from my code which is making me problems at this point of time:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ChangedElements, (changedElement) =>
{
    FrameworkElement element = elementHelper.GetElementFromPanel(changedElement.Value, designerwindow.maskDesignerPanel);
    elementHelper.UpdateElementPositionAndSize(element, designerwindow, inputFieldList);
});
```

"ChangedElements" is the dictionary with the names of the changed WPF elements.
Originally it was of type  but i changed it to  so the key and the value contain the name/identifier of the control.
"designerWindow" is a reference to the WPF window and "maskDesignerPanel" the name of the canvas.
At run-time i get an error inside the method GetElementFromPanel when i try to get the element from the children collection of the canvas.
In that case i cannot access the children collection because it belongs to the main thread.

Here the code of the method GetElementFromPanel:

```
    public FrameworkElement GetElementFromPanel(string elementName, Canvas panel)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = null;

        foreach (FrameworkElement child in panel.Children)
        {
            if (child.Name == elementName)
            {
                element = child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return element;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the dispatcher to pull the value?

Comment: You *don't*. You don't need to anyway. There are several dozen duplicate questions that show how to use async/await, IProgress< T> or no synchronization at all - if you use data binding you to a ViewModel you won't have to worry about cross-thread access. Modifying a ViewModel property and raising the INotifyPropertyChanged event is enough to let WPF know that *it* needs to go and pull the changes

Comment: PS, don't try to use dispatchers or .Invoke. That's a) not needed since async/await was introduced and b) it's bad WPF. Use data binding, don't try to modify the controls directly

Comment: `For optimizing the speed of the updates`  do you have a performance issue? If you do, multithreading isn't the answer. The applications you see that allow dragging/moving objects on screen don't use multithreading. They limit redraws to avoid jerkiness. Eg, they *don't* update the UI until the operation is finished, or they disable UI updates. Or they store movements and changes in a list and only apply them at the end of the dragging operation. WPF itself allows you to specify animations, transitions, storyboards

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I don't modify the controls directly. I just want to save their positions and sizes to one of my database tables.

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything with the UI thread, or modify the controls. Why are you asking about Parallel.Foreach then?

Comment: In any case, the controls aren't your data. They are how you visualize your data. When you move something, you move *your* data, not its icon or visualization.

Comment: BTW you can *serialized* a container using the [XamlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: Adding to Panagiotis's fine comments, look into _deferred updating_ via _**batching** during application idle_ or equivalent if you must populate a control with lots of data over time rather than all at once

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I have serialized the Canvas and all controls to a XAML which is even stored in the database. But i need to save the control positions and sizes in another table. Because there can be a few hundred controls per mask and my customer dont want to wait more than half a minute, i wanted to make the updates parallel.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** 
If you have thousands of elements and high frequency of updates quick and cheap way to speedup GetElementFromPanel: place all elements into Dictionary<,> by unique name key, so you don't have to scan all children's every time.

About multithreading

1. Before doing optimization you should prove your assumptions with profiler, what part of your code are heavy?
2. If you see that updates of UI is slow, there is no need to do multithreading (all your threads will wait for main UI thread)
3. If you see that some part of algorithm are slow then optimize it (not UI interaction, I mean algorithm exactly)
4. Just push heavy code away of UI
5. If algorithm still slow make sure that algorithm are parallelizable if so you can go one of this ways:

a. Dispatcher.Invoke Method:  just run some pieces of code that refresh ui
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

b. Use producer-Consumer pattern with something like BlockingCollection.
Push data to process, process in some number of threads, then push results in main thread to show results
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview

c. Use reactive programming
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx

d. If you want just remove ui freezes use async/await or TPL directly to run heavy code away of UI thread.

.... much many another ways

Also before doing multithreading you better to unravel and split ui-get part, process part and ui-refresh part of code.